# Reading/Writing a file in Java Error

Tags: java, input, io, output, filereader

I'm trying to do this assignment:

Write a program that reads a file and writes a copy of the file to another file with line numbers inserted.

So far, I have written this much of the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question43 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("Assign4.txt") );


    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("FileOut.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

    String []array = new String[10];

    int indx = 0;
    while(fileIn.hasNext( ) )
    {
        array[indx] = fileIn.nextLine( );
    }

    fileIn.close();

    int num = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        output.println(num+"\t"+array[i]);
    }
}
}
```

When I click run, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Assign4.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Question43.main(Question43.java:8)
```

Can someone please advise me on what to do? Where am I supposed to put the text file named Assign4 so Eclipse IDE can read it? Also, where would the new file be created?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Unless you specify another directory in your project tree, Eclipse and Java expect the file in the *same* directory that you code is being executed from.  So what directory do you have `Question43.java` in  ?

Comment: If your text file is in the same location as your class files, you can also try to get the data as a resource, `Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(Question43.class.getResourceAsStream("Assign4.txt"));`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks! This did the trick. But the file that is outputted is empty. Any advise on how I would be able to copy the contents of the original file and have it outputted in the output file?

Comment: Edited my answer to include that issue.

Comment: @selig Thanks for your edit. I appreciate it. However, when I put output.close(); it won't copy over the entire text. Just one line of it if I put it after "output.println(num+"\t"+array[i]);" If I place output.close(); anytime before that statement, I get a blank text file. Any recommendation on how to fix it please?

Comment: You need to close your file **after** you've finished writing to it. I've edited my answer to include an explanation. If the answer answers your question then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse the program is run from the top level directory i.e. the place where the source and bin folders are. If in doubt try

```
   System.out.println((new java.io.File(".")).getAbsolutePath());
```

Which will print out the path of the directory that the program is being run from.

You also need to remember to close your writer after using it to ensure what you've written is flushed - the writer might buffer what you've written and if your program finishes before you flush this buffer then what you've written is lost. So close your writer at the end of the program i.e.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question43 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("Assign4.txt") );


    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("FileOut.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

    String []array = new String[10];

    int indx = 0;
    while(fileIn.hasNext( ) )
    {
        array[indx] = fileIn.nextLine( );
    }

    fileIn.close();

    int num = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        output.println(num+"\t"+array[i]);
    }
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Another comment - you're assuming that your file has exactly 10 lines. To give you more flexibility try using a data structure that grows on demand, for example an `ArrayList`. Also, you don't seem to be incrementing num in your loop - so your lines will all be numbered 1.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Question43 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("Assign4.txt") );


    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("FileOut.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(fileIn.hasNext( ) )
    {
        list.add(fileIn.nextLine( ));
    }

    fileIn.close();

    int num = 1;
    for(String line : list)
    {
        output.println(num+"\t"+line);
        num++;
    }
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Finally, you don't actually need a  data structure at all as you can write to your output file as you read your input file i.e.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question43 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("Assign4.txt") );


    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("FileOut.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

    int num = 1;
    while(fileIn.hasNext( ) )
    {
        String line = fileIn.nextLine( );
        output.println(num+"\t"+line);
        num++;
    }

    fileIn.close();
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please specify the path for Assign4.txt file. Scanner cann't find the path you specified. Specify path from root directory of your project